# Maven is not downloading jar files for spring framework

Tags: spring, maven

I have tried various versions. Please help, I am new at this. pom file is included below

Here is my pom dependencies code. please let me know the possible errors or the solutions.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: you may include the console output with the error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include spring web starter dependency as that is more required to start the process, also internet is required to download the dependency everytime you extract the package into IDE. So try this way it can be sorted out. else reply back in same loop so we can sort it out.

Use this link to get the dependency. [Starter Web](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web/2.3.4.RELEASE)

Comment: Thanks, it worked, along with some other maven settings had to be done.

Comment: Even if this answer is solving the problem, I really wonder how come the answerer guessed what was the problem.. as question does not include enough information, and therefore, it won't serve as a good source of help for the further readers.